# VSTS taking too long to run npm build

Tags: reactjs, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I've a very basic react app (created using `create-react-app`, then ejected), with custom webpack configuration (just for optimized code splitting), the app build ok on my machine using `npm run build`, but takes too long using VSTS build.

I've only 3 build steps:
- npm install
- npm run build (this is the one that takes too long to complete, then it canceled by VSTS as it exceeds the maximum execution time of 60)
- Publish artifacts

[image: VSTS build exceed 60 minutes then canceled]

[image: Local build takes no time]

Comment: its probably because you are getting prompted for something and it basically hangs

Comment: @4c74356b41 your comment gives me an idea, I was using a webpack plugin that display bundle analysis, and it was blocking the build because it was opening a temp server to display the bundle size graph, thanks

Answer (score 1):

For your issue,you could add the following script as one of the root fields(replacing the generic path with the path you want to use) in the package.json , e.g.

```
{
  // ...
  "scripts": {
    // ...
  },
  "homepage": "https://example.com"
}
```